# Can I use Corel PaintShop Pro for creating mocks?

Tags: gui-design, tools

I used Adobe Photoshop previously for creating mocks. The current project sponsor suggests Corel PaintShop Pro instead. I couldn't find any info for creating mocks from the scratch using this tool. Can you please suggest if Corel Paintshop Pro is a good option and point me to any tutorials that can help me get started. Thank you.

Comment: Corel for making mock ups? I know Corel Paintshop Pro as an extensive photo editor, just like Photoshop is. Both applications are developed for that particular usage. I would recommend looking into applications designed specifically for making mock-ups, like [Axure](http://www.axure.com/), [Balsamiq](http://balsamiq.com/) or [Sketch](http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/)

Comment: @Paul Depends if we're talking about high-fidelity visual mockups or wireframes.

Comment: Yes, I need to create pixel-perfect high-fidelity mocks.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the application which you can master the most. Be it Microsoft Excel, Balsamiq, Photoshop, Corel Draw or Corel Paintshop Pro. But be sure to make the outcome look like muckups so you don't confuse your stakeholders that you've already built the application. If a mockup look too good, you will have less chance to get the hours you need for implementation.